# Woo commerce error Please enter an address to continue even enabled billing and shipping country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I got an error `'Please enter an address to continue'` once I clicked on place order. I enabled `shipping` and `billing` default field but still getting same error.

I have do some researched on this but I have not found any solution for this.

I have also tried to remove default field using filter hooks.

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_country', 'change_default_checkout_country_and_state' );
add_filter( 'default_checkout_shipping_country', 'change_default_checkout_country_and_state' );
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_state', 'change_default_checkout_country_and_state' );
add_filter( 'default_checkout_shipping_state', 'change_default_checkout_country_and_state' );
function change_default_checkout_country_and_state( $default ) {
    return null;
}*
```

How can i resolve this error? Someone can help me how to resolve this error once I place an order.

Comment: I still getting same error.